# How to solve Error: view is not defined in angularjs on routing to a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[error image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tBb9.png)
Im getting this error in firebug. 
*This is my code and i'm using angular version 1.4.7 and jquery version 1.11.3*

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
      title: 'dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'home.htm',
      caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
      controller: function($scope, $http, $timeout, $rootScope) {
        $scope.controllerName = "HomeController";




        $http({
            method: "GET",
            //url: "User/NewsData.php",
            params: {
              //page: "Get"
            }
          })
          .success(function(data) {
            //$scope.News = data;

          });


        //jQuery(window).trigger("resize");

      }
    }).


    when('/Grocery', {
      title: 'Grocery',
      templateUrl: 'layout.htm',

      caseInsensitiveMatch: true,

      controller: function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $route, $location) {
        $scope.controllerName = "Home1Controller";

        $scope.Goto = function(tbname, category, subcategory) {


          var request = $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "getdata.php",
            params: {
              Page: "ProductData",
              Tablename: tbname,
              Category: category,
              Subcategory: subcategory
            },
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
          });
          request.success(function(data) {
            $scope.products = data.products;

          });
        }

      }
    }).
    when('/Beverages', {
      title: 'Beverages',
      templateUrl: 'beverages.htm',

      caseInsensitiveMatch: true,

      controller: function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.controllerName = "Home1Controller";

        $scope.Goto = function(tbname, category, subcategory) {


          var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "getdata.php",
            data: {
              Page: "ProductData",
              ProductName: tbname,
              Category: category,
              Subcategory: subcategory
            },
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
          });
          request.success(function(data) {
            $scope.products = response.products;

          });
        }

      }
    }).

    when('/Households', {
      title: 'Households',
      templateUrl: 'households.htm',

      caseInsensitiveMatch: true,

      controller: function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.controllerName = "Home1Controller";

        $scope.Goto = function(tbname, category, subcategory) {


          var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "getdata.php",
            data: {
              Page: "ProductData",
              ProductName: tbname,
              Category: category,
              Subcategory: subcategory
            },
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
          });
          request.success(function(data) {
            $scope.products = response.products;

          });
        }

      }
    }).

    when('/BrandedFood', {
      title: 'BrandedFood',
      templateUrl: 'brandedfoods.htm',

      caseInsensitiveMatch: true,

      controller: function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.controllerName = "Home1Controller";

        $scope.Goto = function(tbname, category, subcategory) {


          var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "getdata.php",
            data: {
              Page: "ProductData",
              ProductName: tbname,
              Category: category,
              Subcategory: subcategory
            },
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
          });
          request.success(function(data) {
            $scope.products = response.products;

          });
        }

      }
    }).

    when('/PersonalCare', {
      title: 'PersonalCare',
      templateUrl: 'personalcare.htm',

      caseInsensitiveMatch: true,

      controller: function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.controllerName = "Home1Controller";



      }
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
  }
]);

app.controller('MainCrtl', function($scope, $route, $http, $timeout, $location, $rootScope) {
  $scope.init = function(tbname, category, Type) {
    var request = $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "navigationData.php",
      data: {
        Page: "TabData",
        Tablename: tbname,
        Category: category,
        Typedata: Type
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }

    });
    request.success(function(data) {
      $scope.tabdata = data.Details;

    });
  }
});

app.controller('sliderCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout, $location, $rootScope) {
  $http.get("slideData.php")
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.names = response.image_link;
    });
});

app.controller('tabCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, $rootScope) {
  $scope.init = function(tbname, category, Type) {
    var request = $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "navigationData.php",
      data: {
        Page: "TabData",
        Tablename: tbname,
        Category: category,
        Typedata: Type
      },

    });
    request.success(function(data) {
      $scope.tabdata = data.Details;

    });
  }
});
```

I have ng-href with ng-click in anchor tag in html on click it is displaying html but im getting the above error. layout.htm is the html page, where the fetched data from php is not displaying.

Error:- This is the error i'm getting in firebug....

Error: view is not defined
@http:'//www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js' line 339 > eval:3:1
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http:'//www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js' line 339 > eval:3148:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.add@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js' line 339 > eval:3194:7
jQuery.fn.ready@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js line 339' > eval:3428:2
@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js' line 339 > eval:2:1
.globalEval/<@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js':339:5
.globalEval@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js':338:1
.domManip@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js':5985:1
.append@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js':5758:1
.html/<@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js':5884:5
jQuery.access@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js:4157:5
.html@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js':5848:1
ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular-route.js':971:7
invokeLinkFn@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular.1.4.7.js':8789:9
nodeLinkFn@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular.1.4.7.js':8289:1
compositeLinkFn@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular.1.4.7.js':7680:13
publicLinkFn@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular.1.4.7.js':7555:30
createBoundTranscludeFn/boundTranscludeFn@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular.1.4.7.js':7699:1
controllersBoundTransclude@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular.1.4.7.js':8316:18
update@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular-route.js':935:25
$RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular.1.4.7.js':16311:15
commitRoute/<@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular-route.js':619:15
processQueue@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular.1.4.7.js':14745:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http'://www.domain.com/Angular/assets/js/angular.1.4.7.js':14761:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get"]

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Your approach to the problem on **Stackoverflow** is not correct . Please give some more details and be a little specific to your problem. As @UncleRico says , without any code , we can't solve your problem.

Comment: Now i have given code, can you answer sir.

Answer (score 1):

I found it! View is not defined.
[image: Here!]